# data.table lapply .SD slow down drastically with increase number of columns

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a 20k x 60k table for aggregation, and am experimenting ways to do it with both high memory usage efficiency and speed efficiency.  I noticed that the speed of data.table decrease drastically with increase number of columns.  For example:

```
library(data.table)  
# a 200 x 1,000 table.
test_dt= data.table(sample= rep(1:100,2), value= matrix(sample(6e07, 2e05), nrow = 200 ))
system.time(test_dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by= sample, .SDcols= colnames(test_dt)[-1]])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.470   0.009   0.117 

# a 200 x 10, 000 table
test_dt= data.table(sample= rep(1:100,2), value= matrix(sample(6e07, 2e06), nrow = 200 ))
system.time(test_dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by= sample, .SDcols= colnames(test_dt)[-1]])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 15.055   0.603  15.334
```

Any explanation about this non-linear (100 times slow-down over 10 times column) increase in time?  One way to solve this is to melt it into long DT.  However, it eats many folds more memory.  Is there a way to achieve a reconciliation between the memory usage and speed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a similar result to the OP:

```
# a 200 x 10, 000 table
set.seed(1)
test_dt= data.table(sample= rep(1:100,2), value= matrix(sample(6e07, 2e06), nrow = 200 ))[, 
  (2:10001) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=2:10001]
system.time(z <- test_dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by= sample])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   12.27    0.00   12.26
```

(I'm converting to numeric since it's pretty clear these are to be treated as floats; and adding `set.seed` so it's easier to compare results if necessary.)

> Any explanation about this non-linear (100 times slow-down over 10 times column) increase in time?

Generally, data.tables and data.frames are optimized to support grouping rows/observations together rather than iterating over a huge number of columns. I'm guessing your approach is running into your RAM limit and using swap memory... though I don't really know much about that.

I think that if you want to benefit fully from the speed of the data.table package, you may need to conform to its natural storage formats. As seen below, it makes a significant difference.

> One way to solve this is to melt it into long DT. However, it eats many folds more memory. Is there a way to achieve a reconciliation between the memory usage and speed?

I think the best approach is to get more RAM and keep the data in long form. I'm seeing the melted table at around twice the size, but the speed of the computation there is over 100x faster.

```
test_mdt = melt(test_dt, id = "sample")[, variable := match(variable, unique(variable))]

system.time(mz <- test_mdt[, .(res = mean(value)), by=.(sample, variable)])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.11    0.00    0.11 

object.size(test_dt)  # 17.8 MB
object.size(test_mdt) # 32.0 MB
```

Alternately, if every sample has the same size, use a list of matrices or maybe an array:

```
test_dt[, g := rowid(sample)]
test_mats = lapply( split(test_dt[, !"sample"], by="g", keep.by=FALSE), as.matrix )
system.time(matz <- Reduce(`+`, test_mats)/length(test_mats))
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0 

object.size(test_mats) # 17.3 MB
```

Comment: Hi Frank,  Thanks for the answer.  In terms of swapping memory, for the test case (with 2e06 data), it definitely not hits the memory limit.  The last solution is an amazing example that mean is slow compared to matrix manipulation.  However, for my case, the number of samples in each group are varied in real data.   In conclusion, I believe long DT, even though with memory issue, is still the way to go.  I finished the task by cut the wide DT by columns, melt each into long DT and send them to server one by one.